# stateParams in url of abstract state, ui-router, angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

if i have an abstract state:

```
$stateProvider.
        state('drug', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/drug/:drugId',
            template:
            '<ui-view></ui-view>',
            resolve: {
                drugId : ['$stateParams', function($stateParams){
                    return $stateParams.drugId;
                }]
            }
        }
```

that have some child states, in form: drug.x,drug.y
and I want to choose, in one place in the app, a drugId that will come through the abstract state to all the child states, so that after that when i call to 'drug.x' state, it'll have the drugId value - 
where and how i do this one call to drug state with drugId param?
I know that I can't call the abstract state itself.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already done the tricky part by exposing $stateParams.drugId as a resolve.  Now you just inject it into your substate controller like so:

```
$stateProvider.state('drug.x', {
  controller: function(drugId) { } // drugId is injected from the resolve you defined in 'drug'
}
```

To provide the parameter to `drug.x`, you simply add it to the transition parameters:

`$state.go('drug.x', { drugId: 123 })`;

or

`<a ui-sref="drug.x({ drugId: scopeVariable })">Go to drug.x for {{ scopeVariable }}</a>`

Comment: what i'm asked is where and when can i pass drugId into the abstract state? thanks

Comment: When transitioning to 'drug.x', the abstract state 'drug' will "receive" the parameter.  When applying a set of parameters to a transition, those parameters are made available to the "to state", as well as all the parent states of that "to state", including abstract states.  Said another way, you don't pass parameters to states, you provide them to a transition.

Comment: so, if i passed this param to one child of drug, this param will stay in it's value for all it's children until i'll call other child state with other param value? thanks!

Comment: Basically, yes.  If you `$state.go('drug.y')` or `$state.go('drug.x.a')`, the drugId stays the same.  This, by the way, is due to `go` default options including `inherit: true`.  See docs for `$state.go`: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state.  If you are on `drug.x` and you do `$state.go(drug.x, { drugId: 456 })`, the parameter obviously changes as well.

Comment: Also, do not think of "passing parameters to states". You transition to a state and supply parameters for the *transition* (not for the state).