# Can someone explain me when $stateParams really becames available?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to initialize some variables in a child state that require $stateParams.

For that I've registered the state using the following:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/parent',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        controller: 'ParentCtrl',
    }).state('parent.child', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.someFunction();
        },
    });
```

This is my controller:

```
module.controller('ParentCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        //calling a function in the scope inherited from parent controller
        $scope.someFunction = function () {
            //$stateParams isn't available.
        }
    }]);
```

But when someFunction is called the params in $stateParams are undefined.

But if instead of calling the function from `ParentCtrl` I run from inside the state controller like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('parent', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/parent',
        template: '<div ui-view></div>',
        controller: 'ParentCtrl',
    })
    .state('parent.child', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
            //$stateParams is available
        },
    });
```

I can access the params on $stateParams.

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: @RadimKöhler Maybe I missed something but how $stateParams relate to $scope inheritance? Because my doubts concern the fact that a function called by the child controller run before $stateParams is populated with params. But I can use params inside the same child controller.

Comment: Are you trying to access parent route.  As explained in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663146/stateparams-in-url-of-abstract-state-ui-router-angularjs), you can get $stateParams in the parent controller or in resolve.  I [created a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vqovhyezWkIUMJGHlZ2j?p=preview) extending this to include a parent controller - [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vqovhyezWkIUMJGHlZ2j?p=preview), wherein you have access to stateParams in parent controller without issues.  You are overlooking something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it. It's actually really simple: The problem is that I'm calling from child state a function in the parent state controller that uses the parent state $stateParams that (of course) don't have the right params.

So in order to make it work I would have to inject child state params in the parent controller like this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('parent', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/parent',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    controller: 'ParentCtrl',
}).state('parent.child', {
    url: '/:id',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.someFunction($stateParams);
    },
});
```

It was beginning to answer Mahesh comment that lead me to this conclusion.